# how can I make a field have specific numbers in the order

Tags: mysql, sql

---

hello I have an as3 app. this app divides the users into groups, every group consisting of 3 users.

in my mysql database there is a field in "users_into" table that identifies the number of user in his group.
this field is called "num_in_group" and its value must be a number between 1 and 3 for every user.

For clarification

The first user who registered in the application will have number 1 and the second one will have number 2 and the third one will have number 3 ---and the forth one will have 1 (not 4) ----- and fifth one will have 2 and sixth one will have 3 and seventh one will have 1 again and so on ......

so my question is how can I make the field have numbers 1 , 2 , 3 , 1 , 2 , 3 in the order constantly

Comment: This feature is built in to the auto-increment behaviour of MyISAM tables, but, if it was me, I'd just store a regular auto-incrementing id and calculate this secondary value 'on-the-fly'

Comment: so my question is how can I make the field have numbers 1 , 2 , 3 , 1 , 2 , 3 in the order constantly.  simply use order by num_in_group

Answer (score 0):

One option which you might find acceptable would be to use `ROW_NUMBER()` and generate this value at the time you query:

```
SELECT
    id,
    1 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) - 1) % 3 AS seq
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id;
```

The above assumes that `id` is an auto increment column, with a unique idea for each user.  The only potential problem with this approach is that the `id` might not always be sequential or increasing.  Assuming you can tolerate the vast majority of users have an even spread of 1, 2, and 3 values, then the above might be acceptable to you.